# What is the syntax for Corda CRaSH shell using the run command

Tags: corda

I am trying to check on the consumed and unconsumed cash states through the Corda CRaSH shell. From the documentations (https://docs.corda.net/releases/release-V2.0/shell.html?highlight=crash%20shell), it says RPC can be evoked using run command in the shell. Is there a better guide than the YAML link? How do I call out the consumed and unconsumed cash states through the shell?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is documented here: https://docs.corda.net/shell.html#querying-the-vault. You can query the node's vault for cash states via the shell as follows:

```
run vaultQuery contractStateType: net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$State
```

However, this defaults to only returning unconsumed states. In theory, you could query for both consumed and unconsumed states using the following syntax:

```
run vaultQueryByCriteria 
    criteria: { status: net.corda.core.node.services.Vault.StateStatus.ALL }, 
    contractStateType: net.corda.finance.contracts.asset.Cash$State
```

However, the `criteria` parameter is of type `QueryCriteria`, which is an abstract class. There is no way via the shell to specify that you want to use the concrete subclass `VaultQueryCriteria`. Therefore, you get back the following error:

> Could not parse as a command: Cannot construct instance of `net.corda.core.node.services.vault.QueryCriteria` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information

Comment: Thanks Joel. I suspected not all the RPC commands can be called in the Shell. Maybe we should add a caveat to the doc? At the moment, there are no caveats and people assumes that all the CordaRPCOps classes can be called until they try.